# how to add active class to current element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a button with classname, and I have created jquery and css as well
but why can't be active

this is my html code

```
<div class="landing-pages-button-content">
     <a class="btn" id="semua">Semua</a>
     <a class="btn" id="pria">Pria</a>
     <a class="btn" id="wanita">Wanita</a>
</div>
```

this id my css file

```
.active, .btn:hover {background-color: #ff7400;color: white; border: none;}
```

and the last this is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".btn").not(this).removeClass("active");
        });

);
```

Comment: You're mising the `}`, check console for the error.

Answer (score 2):

Because you set hover in css, and you are missing "}" of end ready. Please try code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".btn").click(function () {
          $(this).addClass("active");
          $(".btn").not(this).removeClass("active");
      });

});
```

```css
.active{background-color: #ff7400;color: white; border: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="landing-pages-button-content">
     <a class="btn" id="semua">Semua</a>
     <a class="btn" id="pria">Pria</a>
     <a class="btn" id="wanita">Wanita</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".btn").not(this).removeClass("active");
        });

});
```

```css
.active, .btn:hover {background-color: #ff7400;color: white; border: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="landing-pages-button-content">
     <a class="btn" id="semua">Semua</a>
     <a class="btn" id="pria">Pria</a>
     <a class="btn" id="wanita">Wanita</a>
</div>
```

I don't see any problem with your code. just a missing curly bracket.

Comment: i try the code but the result still like just hover not active

Comment: when you click it it added a class active.